# How do you integrate $2\sqrt{-x^2+1}dx$ step by step?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

How do you integrate 
$$2\sqrt{-x^2+1}dx$$ to achieve the answer of
$$\sqrt{-x^2+1}*x+\arcsin(x)$$ like Wolfram Alpha does? Wolfram showed no steps.

Comment: See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).